Is an IGBT comprised of many micro sized transistors, or is it just a single device in itself?
Below is a typical IGBT structure that we studied in the regular course.

Someone told me that there are thousands of small transistors that make up an IGBT. As I understand it, there are a number of parasitic transistors formed as shown in the figure and the rest is all material layers and this whole unit can be called one IGBT. Which is correct?

This structure itself at the micron level and we join several such units to form a bigger IGBT.
It is one big chunk of substrate layers exactly as shown in the figure and there are no other transistors except parasitic BJTs as shown in the figure.
Something else.

Image reference: Electrical 4 U, https://www.electrical4u.com/insulated-gate-bipolar-transistor-igbt/

This will vary from manufacturer to manufacturer. I've seen both single chip IGBTs as well as arrays within one package. Is your question in general or for a certain size?

@winny In general, but I am more interested in power devices with kW level ratings. It is also true that they use multiple IGBT in parallel inside a power module for current sharing. I am still concerned with what goes inside a single chip packaging.

This isn't a complete answer to your question, but too much of an answer for a comment.
I don't know enough about semiconductor manufacturing to tell if a single die (macroscopic level) actually has many IGBT structures in parallel or if it counts as one large. What I do know when I asked the sales rep some years ago, their 600 V ~50 A offering used 7 chips in parallel. This could vary from manufacture to manufacturer depending on their production.
The pros and cons for making IGBTs as several dies versus one large is very similar to making CPUs. Intel went with chiplet design around the Core 2 era which allowed them to sort out defective chiplets and only assemble for example four single core chiplets to make a 4 core CPU. AMD at the time did not, which is why a CPU sold as a 3 core would actually contain 4, with one defective and disabled via laser cutting or microcode. The AMD approach seems to have stopped, but I've been out of the game for too long to keep track.
The multiple chip approach allows for higher yield from a wafer since a small defect would only affect the die where it's located. Big die=big loss. But this comes with a packaging disadvantage (less so for an IGBT than a CPU). Scaling is also easier since you only need one base design and can throw in as many dies as you need if there the customer demand for a bigger or smaller IGBT.
If you are more interested, I would recommend you ask the sales rep and/or buy a few different ones and crack them open. I would suspect you will find multiple dies in most IGBTs.
